grid-template-columns with minmax does not shrink when it should
I have a basic layout - a container with several cards. Every card must have a width from 300px to 500px.
I would suggest a simple grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 500px)) should work, but it does not. For the 700px container it should fit two 350px cards in a single row, but it does not do it:


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 500px));
  gap: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.card {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>  



I tried to use grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr)) and adding max-width: 500px to the card, and it's almost what I need except the gap between cards.
If there are two cards, and container is 2000px width, I need both 500px cards to be drawn at the left with 20px gap. I have the huge gap instead.


.container {
  width: 2000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>  



Is it possible to force the gap to be 20px? And I'm not allowed to use media queries because the whole thing might be used in different places with/without submenu, etc.

only two coliumns?

auto-fit is not what you seem to require. auto-fill seems to suit your requirements.


.container {
  width: 2000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>




It is not a 100% solution. A card should stretch to 500px if possible. For example, 2 cards on 1200px screen should take 500px each. Here I recreated the requested behavior with javascript, https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/ag6n2scj/1/. Is it possible to achieve with CSS?
